# How to change (move forward/backward) an iterator in range based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I just want to get an element that is in the next iteration (using range-based for loop)

I have tried something like that:

*(&x+1) is supposed to mean "i+1" if "i" would have been an iterator here

```cpp
bool factorChain(std::vector<int> arr) {
    for(auto& x : arr)
    {
        if (*(&x+1)%x != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want it to work like that, but with a range-based for loop:

```
bool factorChain(std::vector<int> arr) {
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i+1]%arr[i]!=0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or this might be more helpful:

```
bool factorChain(std::vector<int> arr) {
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = arr.begin();
          iter != arr.end()-1; ++iter){
        if(*(iter+1)%*(iter)!=0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you need such control over the loop, it's best - clearer, more readable - to spell out the iterator-based loop, and not attempt pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that `*(&x+1)` exhibits undefined behavior when `x` refers to the last element. With range-based loop, there's no way to stop one element short of the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really bent on using range-based loop, you can do something like this:

```
bool factorChain(std::vector<int> arr) {
    int* prev = nullptr;
    for(auto& x : arr)
    {
        if (prev && x % *prev != 0) return false;
        prev = &x;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, at this point it's likely clearer, more readable to just spell out an iterator-based or index-based loop, than to try and salvage range-based one.

---

Now, for extra subtlety points, how about something like this:

```
bool factorChain(std::vector<int> arr) {
    return std::adjacent_find(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
        [](int prev, int next) { return next % prev != 0; })
    == arr.end();
}
```

Comment: I feel that `adjacent_find` is *the* way to go in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to get an element that is in the next iteration (using
>   range-based for loop)

The answer to your question is simple: don't abuse features.  The range-for loop is for the simplest case where you want to traverse the array one by one.  If you want fine-grained control over the traversal, don't use the range-for loop.  Your last two approaches are fine, so don't over-complicate things.

By the way, `arr` should be passed by const reference to avoid unnecessary copy.

Comment: okay, just wanted to know what's wrong with my try to refer to the next element with *(&x+1)
I've been learning these range based looped today and it seemed like a simple problem at first, so I've been sure that it is possible to solve without creating a variable.

Comment: @Olgierd The problem with your attempt is that *(&x+1) exhibits undefined behavior when x refers to the last element. With range-based loop, there's no way to stop one element short of the end. – Igor Tandetnik 16 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot.

I have written `iterators_of`, a range adapter that takes a range and reyurns a range of the iterators.

You start with a range type:

```
template<class It>
struct range{
  It b,e;
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
};
```

that is a minimal one.

Then an indexing iteratoroid:

```
template<class T>
struct indexing_iteratoid{
  using this_t=indexing_iteratoid;  
   T t;
   T operator*()const{return t;}
   void operator++()&{++t;}
   friend bool operator==(this_t const& lhs, this_t const& rhs){return lhs.t==rhs.t;}
   friend bool operator!=(this_t const& lhs, this_t const& rhs){return lhs.t!=rhs.t;}
};
```

again, minimal and stripped down.

```
template<class R>
auto iterstors_of(R&& r){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto b=begin(r), e=end(r);
  return range{ indexing_iteratoid{ b },  indexing_iteratoid{ e } };
}
```

and now you can:

```
for(auto it:iterators_of( vec ) ){
}
```

and `*it` is an element, and `*std::next(it)` is the next element (care not to go over the end), etc.

Code is based off code that works, but this was typed on a phone and probabky has tpyos.

It is an iteratoid because it isn't an iterator; it just qualifies for `for(:)` loops.

It is indexing, because its primary use is to store size_t's: pass it `0` and `r.size()` and you count from `0` to `size()-1`.